# div with two div's inside, when I go from one div to another, using onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, html, css

The think is that I have a div (let's call it "A") that have two div's ("B" and "C") inside , both div's ("B" and "C") have a margin of 5px. The "C" div have a style.display='none', so at first you don't see it, what I want to do, Is using onMouseOver event on the div "A", when I click "B", "C"  shows up, and when I go outside div "A", the div "C" (Display: none) again

Here is some code to se all this in a better way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>A.CAT</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="A" onMouseOut="outA()">
   <div id="B" onClick="clickB()" class="buttonB">B</div>
   <div id="C" class="buttonC">C</div>
</div>

<script>
function outA()
{
   document.getElementById("C").style.display="none";
}

function clickB()
{
   document.getElementById("C").style.display="block";
}

</script>

<style>
.buttonB
{
  border: blue 2px solid;
  margin:5px;
}

.buttonC
{
  border: blue 2px solid;
  margin:5px;
  display:none;
}
</style>
</body>
```

The problem is that when I go outside the div "B" to try to achive "C", and I pass thow the border, the program detects that I go outside the div "A" and execute the function out(), and I cannot reach div "C"

I've tried to use pointer-events: none, but then I cannot use C as a button.

Comment: And where is the `mouseover` function in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onMouseLeave instead:

```
 <div id="A" onMouseLeave="outA()">
   <div id="B" onClick="clickB()" class="buttonB">B</div>
   <div id="C" class="buttonC">C</div>
</div>
```

Mouse out doesn't work here because the mouse out event will bubble up from the child (B) when you leave the child and call the function. Where as mouse leave will not bubble up from the child and the function is only called when you actually leave the parent.

Comment: It works, but only for some browsers (Chrome, Mozilla)

Dosen't work for Safari, Miscrosoft edge, Internet Explorer